# Inactive wireless -> disconnect, why?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, connection

My computer disconnects from the wireless Internet whenever I'm inactive for like 5 or 10 minutes. How can I fix this?

Do I have to change some settings in my phone/computer (ping)? How to do that?

I think it's my servers fault that they disconnect inactive users. I log in 15 times a day because of this.

Comment: can you please explain more? the more information you give about your setup, the more likely someone will have an answer, at this point there could be 500 different reasons, help us narrow it down. for having 100+ rep, you should know better.

Comment: Here is some basic information which is missing: --- OS Windows / Linux / OS X ... and version --- Does the wireless connection disconnect (all network services stop working, OS indicates no connection) or just a single service disconnects? --- Which kind of Wireless connection do you use? WiFi / CDMA or other 3G / etc.

Comment: The problem is I'm on a phone so very hard to write unfortunately. But the issue is that I think my uni (which is in charge of the internet connection) sends ping and if phone/laptop don't answer->disconnect. How make accept ping?

Comment: stop using the word: ping, it makes absolutely no sense in this question

Comment: Do you have any better suggestions?